# Removing header rendering in specific rails .html.erb file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm rendering a header universally across my application in layouts/application.html.erb.

I'd like to make the header not appear in a specific foo.html.erb file.

What's the syntax for un-rendering a universal layout?

EDIT:

The controller for the layout is a devise controller, specifically Sessions Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the controller and action that renders the template foo.html.erb is 'things#foo' and the path to this action is things_path. You can wrap the header in conditional tags as follows

```
<% unless request.path == things_path %>
<% end %>
```

. There are several ways to achieve this, but here is one.

Comment: The one drawback is that the condition is tied to the controller rendering the template and not the controller itself, so unless you specified the above conditional for each path leading to the template foo.html.erb, the header could still be rendered through some other controlller action.

Answer (score 3):

in your controller you can set the layout to false (or another layout), if false then you need all of the html,head,body tags in your view file

```
class BarController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    render :layout => false # render foo.html.erb with no layout
  end 
end
```

see section 2.2.11.2 from the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

**EDIT:** including devise layout overrides

in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
Devise::SessionsController.layout "bar"
Devise::RegistrationsController.layout "foo"
Devise::ConfirmationsController.layout false # never tried this, guessing it would work
Devise::UnlocksController.layout "bar"
Devise::PasswordsController.layout "foo"
```

also see the wiki post - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts has at least one other way

Comment: what if the controller is a hidden devise controller?

Comment: also forgot to mention, if changing files in config/initializers you will probably need to restart rails server to see the changes